# Зачем устанавливать nginx для ghost blog?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ghost-blog

Настроил в Ghost config.js  server host: 0.0.0.0  port: 80 и по домену все запускаеться. Не могу понять зачем устанавливать ngnix если ghost работает?

Comment: а зачем вы собрались устанавливать *nginx*?

Comment: прочитал много мануалов по установке везде предлагаеться установить nginx, из за любопытсво покопался в конфигах Ghost и настроил порты, и возник вопрос зачем мне устанавливать nginx если и так все запускайтся так как нужно.

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Answer (score 2):

Nginx - это веб-сервер. Его killer feature - это способность *управлять* подключениями. Ghost, со своей стороны - это просто приложение со встроенным непроизводительным веб-сервером. Несмотря на то, что оно действительно может справляться без nginx, и несмотря на то, что nginx сам по себе никак его не ускорит, проксирующий nginx все равно реализует кучу функционала, который на первый взгляд может показаться не таким и полезным, но зачастую спасает:

- Отдача статических файлов, которая оптимизирована по самое не могу
- Фильтрация трафика
- Ограничение трафика, которое позволит не обвалить бэкенд
- Атомарные перезагрузки конфигурации, благодаря которым возможен хот-своп приложений
- Способность слушать кучу доменов на одном порту - в данном случае этот сервер уже занят Ghost, и второе приложение на нем разместить физически невозможно
- Балансировка нагрузки
- Возможность в любой момент вынести приложение на другой сервер
- Логирование запросов и ошибок, в конце концов
- Реализация SSL

Nginx действительно работает по тому же протоколу, что и Ghost, но это не значит, что последний умеет всё то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш сервер выдаёт приемлемые для вас результаты при нагрузочном тестировании на планируемую нагрузку, то кэширующий *http-proxy* вам, действительно, не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

При больших нагрузка не справится ghost. Он, как минимум, не умеет балансить, проксировать.

Да и одна из главных причин ставить `nginx` - статические файлы раздавать.